# How set app version in ember electron app?

Tags: electron

I need set app versio like `1.006`

I use ember-electron
Here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehY0V.png)

Answer (score 1):

I generally follow [semvar](https://semver.org) versioning in my ember electron applications and use the package.json version as my app version.  You can maintain your version number in one place (package.json) and use it wherever needed in your app.

To access the version in package.json, add the following code to your config/enviroment.js file:

```
/* eslint-env node */
'use strict';

const pjson = require('../package.json');

module.exports = function (environment) {

   // ENV variables, etc ...

   APP: {
     appVersion: pjson.version,
     appAuthor: pjson.author
   },

  // remainder of environment.js ...

  return ENV;
};
```

Using app/controllers/application.js:

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import config from '../config/environment';

export default Controller.extend({
   appVer: config.APP.appVersion

});
```

your can then use `{{appVer}}` wherever you want to display your version number.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question.  You assign the executable version using the electron-packager.  If you are using electron-forge with ember-electron you can set the version in the Windows installer configuration: _electronWinstallerConfig_ See [electron-forge](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge) and [windows installer](https://github.com/electron/windows-installer#usage)